# Mac OS X and root login enabled

Tags: macos, authentication, ssh

I am running OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8, and I've enabled root login through Directory Utility. It has a password.

I get an error when I try to `ssh root@localhost`.

```
ssh -v root@localhost
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/known_hosts:47
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/rrazavipour-lp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive

Password:

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

What I am doing wrong? I know I have the password correct.

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/sshd_config` add an entry that says

`PermitRootLogin yes`

And then restart sshd.